# Array format unexpected when combined columns into a new one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 3 columns in a dataframe:

df:

```
A |B|C
hi| |dear
```

In order to combine them into a new column D, I did:

```
df['D'] = [[x, y, z] for x, y, z in zip(df.A, df.B, df.C)]
```

Unfortunately, the outcome looks like this: `[hi, ,dear]` . 
How do I format it to this: `[hi dear]` or `[hi-dear]` by essentially removing null values (and commas associated) and then connecting the remaining values with space or dash? 
Any help is appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use methods like `"".join()` and `.strip()`? Do these not work with pandas dataframes? I'm not an expert on those

Comment: @Reedinationer they would, and would probably be faster than the `.str` accessor  methods that Pandas supplies, which people (rightly) think would be vectorized but aren't.

Comment: I get an error: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found . why is that?

Answer (score 2):

`apply` is a handy tool to apply a simple function to all the rows of a dataframe. Here you could join the columns with a space character and replace any number of spaces with a single one. Code could be:

```
import re

blanks = re.compile(' +')
df['D'] = df.apply(lambda x: blanks.sub(' ', ' '.join(x)), axis=1)
```

`df` will become as expected:

```
    A B     C        D
0  hi    dear  hi dear
```

Comment: I get this error: TypeError: ('sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found', 'occurred at index 0' What would I need to do next?

Comment: @Tini you would need to specify it as a string with `str()`. It thinks you have something like 9 but when you say `str(9)` -> "9"

Comment: I like your answer @Reedinationer. You could also do it with the Series.str methods like this: `df.apply(' '.join, axis=1).str.replace('\s+', ' ')`

Answer (score 0):

Since you tag `pandas`

```
df.mask(df=='').stack().groupby(level=0).apply('+'.join).tolist()
['hi+dear']
```